# "Не равно" в связке с логическим "или"

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, логические-выражения

Дан одномерный массив типа `char a[i]`, где `i` - номер элемента. Необходимо, чтобы был осуществлен выход из цикла `while`:

```
while (!(a[i] == 48) || !(a[i] == 49))
      i++;
while (a[i] != 48) || a[i] != 49)) 
      i++;
```

Пытался так пробовать - не работает. То бишь, когда код символа равен `48` или `49` должен произойти выход из цикла, а этого не происходит. Что не так?

Comment: Пока число не равно 48 ИЛИ не равно 49... так ведь какое не возьми - по-любому одному из двух оно не равно...

Comment: Потому что условие цикла всегда истинно.

Comment: у вас первый цикл отрабатывает пока не встречается `48` или `49`, а второй цикл работает пока встреченные символы равны `48` или `49`. Не понятно зачем вас сразу два этих цикла.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, автор имеет в виду, что пробовал два разных варианта цикла. (Хотя они и идентичны).

Answer (score 3):

Условие "когда x равно 48 или 49" (или, более математично, "когда x равно 48 или когда x равно 49") выглядит так:

```
(x == 48) || (x == 49)
```

Можно и без скобок, но я оставил для наглядности.

Значит, продолжать цикл, если условие НЕ выполнено, т.е.

```
while(!((x == 48) || (x == 49)))
```

Если применить НЕ к *А ИЛИ Б*, то это - *НЕ А И НЕ Б* - т.е. второй вариант

```
while(!(x == 48) && !(x == 49))
```

или, что то же самое

```
while((x != 48) && (x != 49))
```

Т.е. работать, пока код - и не 48, и не 49...

Думаю, проблем подставить вместо `x` - `a[i]` проблемы не составит?

Comment: спасибки, все работает

Answer (score 2):

```
while (!(a[i] == 48) || !(a[i] == 49))
```

означает, что если один из двух условий верно, то продолжить цикл.  Как не крути, то элемент не может быть равен  одновременно и  48  и 49, поэтому одно из двух условий всегда верно, и цикл продолжается.

```
while (a[i] != 48) || a[i] != 49))
```

если тут скобки поставить правильно и написать

```
while ((a[i] != 48) || (a[i] != 49))
```

то это тоже самое, что и первый вариант.

Правильный ответ уже изложил вам [**Harry**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry).