# Здравствуйте у меня проблема с циклом в C++ он постоянно срабатывает

Tags: c++, c++builder

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num, num1, opr;
    char mmsvh;
    cin >> num;
    cin >> opr;
    while (opr != '+' || '-' || 'x' || ':') {
        cout << "Error" << " ";
        cin >> opr;
    }
    cin >> num1;
    if (opr == '+') {
        cout << num + num1 << endl;
    }
    if (opr == '-') {
        cout << num - num1 << endl;
    }
    if (opr == 'x') {
        cout << num * num1 << endl;
    }
    if (opr == ':') {
        cout << num / num1 << endl;
    }



    system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

цикл срабатывает постоянно даже, когда он равен +,-,x,:

операционная система::Windows 10

компилятор::Visual Studio 2017
я новичок в c++

Comment: Выражение `opr != '+' || '-' || 'x' || ':'` делает совсем не то, что вы думаете. Вам надо сравнить переменную с каждым символом отдельно.

Comment: не говоря уже о том, что `opr` читается как число, а не символ...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, так символ и есть число...

Comment: @Eanmos, но не для `cin`'а... хотя если подразумевается ввод "2 43 2", а не "2 + 2", то, конечно, всё в порядке...

Comment: У меня де жа вю или точно такойже вопрос был ранее? я точно такую же ошибку уже видел. возможно, было на англ. сайте, впрочем.

Comment: я советовал бы  предпочитать ООП, стараться  определить класс для таких вычислений: например,  класс  Сalculator...  в классе удобнее инкапсулировать  ваши переменные и функции  для реализации ввода и вычислений

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, вы серьезно?

Answer (score 2):

В C так нельзя. Как и сказал @VTT в комментариях, нужно сравнить переменную с каждым значением отдельно. Т.е.:

```
while (opr != '+' &&
       opr != '-' &&
       opr != 'x' &&
       opr != ':')
```

Да, у Вас в цикле везде вместо `||` нужно поставить `&&` иначе он будет выполняться вечно. Такая же проблема в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783830/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8) вопросе.

Comment: круто. вечный цикл.

Comment: @pavel, точно, слона то и не заметил:)

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
while (opr != '+' || '-' || 'x' || ':') {
        cout << "Error" << " ";
        cin >> opr;
    }
```

на

```
while (opr != '+' && opr != '-' && opr != 'x' && opr != ':') {
        cout << "Error" << " ";
        cin >> opr;
    }
```